# Popup window cancels on touch inside the popup

Tags: android, popupwindow

I am using popup window in my app. I want to dismiss the window when user touch outside the window. I have written the below code for the same and its working. But the issue is I have a scrollview inside my window when I tried to scroll it window itself is canceling. How can i prevent that?

```
 mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.help_popup,
            null);
    mHelpPopup = new PopupWindow(layout, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
    mHelpPopup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    mHelpPopup.setTouchable(true);
    mHelpPopup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    mHelpPopup.setTouchInterceptor(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Logger.get().d("POPUP_WINDOW", "v: " + v.getTag() + " | event: " + event.getAction());
            mHelpPopup.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
    });
    mHelpPopup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CLIP_VERTICAL, (int) helpTxtView.getX(), (int) helpTxtView.getY());
```

Comment: Maybe try checking the event type or view it is being triggered on?

Answer (score 0):

I could find out the answer. It was because of touchinterceptor. when i removed that listener it is working fine.